# DocuSign Send on Behalf of (SOBO) but without a Docusign Account

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

We have a DocuSign REST API application where a user authenticates and create Envelopes. Problem is that the emails being sent contains that user's Name/Email while we want to have the 'operating user's' info--which come from the application itself to show as Name/Email.

From my understanding, the 'operating user' must exist in DocuSign otherwise this will not work as intended? Our DocuSign account is not going to be tied into any CRM/SalesForce data.

Am I right? BTW, I think I can create some generic user and use that user to create/send Envelopes but that's not the preferred route.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only send requests on behalf of another account user, so yes the "operating user" is required to have a DocuSign account.  Additionally, the operating user must be in the **SAME** DocuSign account as the sending user.

When used the name/email address that will show will be the name/email address of the operating user in the account.

Note that you need to enable the following two account settings to use SOBO:

`apiAccountWideAccess`: Specifies that the user can send and manage envelopes for the entire account using the DocuSign API.

`allowSendOnBehalfOf`: Specifies that the user can send envelopes and perform other tasks on behalf of other users through the API.

See SOBO page in API Reference for more info:

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Yes, that is correct to an extent but I could make the API call to work just based on that. I had to also Share my Template using DocuSign console with an 'Everyone' group to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted Egin's Answer above. However, as I mentioned in my Comment to him, I had also had to Share my Template using DocuSign webpage/console. Without the Sharing, I was getting an HTTP Bad Request 400 error:

```
"errorCode": "TEMPLATE_ID_INVALID", "message": "Invalid template ID."
```

HTH.

Thanks.